# Output is still not iterating

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

My program still not iterating even count += 1 is implemented in the code, its seems that the code for count += is not being read. Please bear with me how I post my question.

```
NameInput = int(input("number of students to enter: ")) 
GradeInput = int(input("number of grades per student: "))

students = {}

class Student():
    def GetInfo(students):
        idnum = 0
        count = NameInput

        for c in range(count):
            idnum += 1
            name =(input("Enter Student " + str(idnum) + " Name: "))
            if name in students:
                print ("Student " + name + " has already been entered, please enter again.")
                idnum -= 1
                count += 1                 
            else:
                students[name] = []       
                for r in range(GradeInput):
                    grade =(float(input("Enter Student " + str(idnum) + " Grade: ")))
                    students[name].append(grade)

    def printList(students):
        for key in students:
            print(key)
def main():
    Student.GetInfo(students)

main()
```

Comment: count only get incremented when a name is entered more than once. You probably want to increment it in the `else` block

Comment: Yes. But count is not incremented as if my code for count =+ 1 is not read.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't the `count += 1` itself. You can add some print statements throughout your code to see the value of `count` at various points in the execution.

The problem is that you want to change the number of iterations of your loop from within it.  You wrote your loop:

```
for c in range(count):
```

The value of `count` is read when this statement is reached.  The value is passed to `range()`, and the object returned is used to control the loop.  Changing the value of `count` after this has no effect on your program because it is never used again.

One way to change your code would be like this:

```
c = 0
while c < count:
    ...
    c += 1
```

This approach allows you to add to `count` in order to cause the loop to run more iterations.  It is more code than the simpler `for` loop, but is more flexible.

Comment: The code should actually be `count = 0; while count < NameInput:`, and then `count += 1; idnum += 1` must go at the end of the `else` block. The corresponding `idnum/count` lines in the `if` block also need to be removed.